# Using Webpack to Handle Image Directory

Tags: html, webpack, bundle

I am currently switching a web app to have its assets bundled using Webpack. Bundling JS and CSS was somewhat straightforward. Then came the turn of images. My question is how one can approach bundling images.

In particular, suppose I have `static_src` from which everything originates and `static_compiled` into which the bundled output is placed. I would like the image contents of `static_src/img` to move into `static_compiled/img`. How does one accomplish this?

On another note, is this a sensible approach or am I misunderstanding some philosophy behind Webpack and misusing it?

Current config is roughly like this:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: { index: path.resolve(__dirname, "static_src", "index.js") },
    output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "static_compiled"),
    publicPath: "/static/", // Should match Django STATIC_URL
    filename: "[name].js",  // No filename hashing, Django takes care of this
    chunkFilename: "[id]-[chunkhash].js", // DO have Webpack hash chunk filename, see below
    },
    plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
    ],
    module: {
    rules: [
        {
        test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'}, // to transform JSX into JS
        {
        test: /\.scss$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]},
        {
        test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]},
        {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'},
        {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-inline-loader'},
        /* {
           test: /\.(ico|png|jpg|gif)$/,
           loader: 'file-loader'} */
        {
        test: /\.(ico|png|svg|jpg|gif|jpe?g)$/,
        use: [
            {
            options: {
                name: "[name].[ext]",
                outputPath: "img/"
            },
            loader: "file-loader"
            }
        ]
        }

        
    ],
    },
    resolve: {
    alias: {
            shared: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'bower_components')
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', 'jsx', 'tsx']
    },
    devServer: {
    writeToDisk: true, // Write files to disk in dev mode, so Django can serve the assets
    }
}
```

Comment: Would love to see a self-answer on this.

Comment: @Arthur_J Added the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code I ended up using looks something like this.

`plugins` section:

```
    plugins: [...
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: path.resolve(__dirname, `static_src/img`),
                    to: 'img',
                }
            ]
        }),
```

`module-rules` section:

```
module: {
    rules: [
            { ...

                test: /\.(ico|png|jpg|gif|jpe?g)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: "[name].[ext]",
                            outputPath: "img/"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```